# Anyone know of any completely flavorless syrups?

Tags: baking, syrup

I'm looking for a syrup that has absolutely no flavor... not even the sweetness you find. Just as bland as you can get it (think water). I need this syrup to absorb other flavors as I'm trying to make something savory but the natural sweetness in corn syrup or vegetable glycerin is destroying it. Anyone know of any?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make? Just a thick sauce?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a syrup, but have you considered using either arrowroot powder or cornstarch to make a thick sauce? Arrowroot is the more neutral but often pricier choice.

Comment: I don't know if it'd help, but glucose is less sweet than fructose for the same amount of sugar molecules.

Comment: try e469, carboxymethyl cellulose - there is some sweetness, but you can use much less to archive same thickness than with glycerin. Experiment with gelatin or agar - maybe you'll succeed to get the right texture using weak solutions.

Comment: You've tagged the question [tag:baking]. Does this mean that you need something which is heat-stable up to e.g. 200C?

Comment: Definitely think you need to explain what you're doing to make this make sense.  Do you need the sugar to help yeast rise for example?  Is this affecting the texture of the product (intentionally)?  Are you replacing syrup in a recipe?

Comment: Are you trying to make... gravy?

Answer (score 18):

A syrup is by definition a thick sweet liquid made using sugar. If you are looking to make a thick savory liquid, perhaps you want to look into thickening agents. Starches and plant-based gums are the most common thickening agents. Some examples include:

- Starches: arrowroot, cornstarch, potato starch, tapioca
- Plant-base gums: guar gum, xanthum gum, alginin

Each of these will have its own unique qualities so you might want to research further into which meets your need best.

The two thickener that will most likely result in a clear, "smooth" thickness that is slightly similar to a syrup would be likely gelatin or pectin. However both of these will be much thicker at cooler temperatures. So depending on your application you will need to alter the concentration. Meaning, if your savory liquid is suppose to be consumed at room temperature or cooler, make sure not to added too much of gelatin or pectin. Try to test the thickness of your savory solution by taking a small sample aside and chilling it to room temperature.

Comment: There's no "almost" about that "by definition". Syrup is [a sweet, thick liquid made of sugar and water](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syrup). A non-sweet syrup is like dry water: a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Marti: Unless you use Aqua Dehydrata. Or water powder / instant water, as I like to call it. Patent still pending. It's amazing: One teaspoon powder, add water, and *poof*: Instant water.

Comment: "Unique qualities" includes the exact texture and how it'll vary with temperature so further research is definitely a good idea. I'm not sure I can think of anything that would get as thick as corn syrup without starting to gel up, but hopefully there's something close enough for the OP.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Patent all you want. I've developed a technique to achieve the same thing without even needing the powder! I can't reveal the details right now but I'm looking for commercial backers who can see the potential in this idea.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt : it's already been patented : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_water

Comment: @Joe What a scam; it took me two seconds to find prior art: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice

Comment: @acbabis : ice isn't of much use in farming.  Dry water is : http://modernfarmer.com/2013/07/powdered-water-just-add-water/

Comment: @joe: Pffff. Inferior stuff. It still contains 95% liquid water. Not exactly what I call dehydrated water. My freeze-drying method removes virtually all the water from the water, leaving a clean, odorless, powder.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt : it *can* contain 95% water.  It binds water to keep it dry, but it can still come out through some processes.

Comment: @Joe: I trust you, but mine doesn't have any water in the water any more. Just clean, dehydrated, waterless water powder, which just needs a drop of water to turn the water powder in to water. And you _do_ realize I'm just mucking about, right?

Comment: Oh, and before I forget, +1 for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Achieving a syrup-like consistency necessitates something like a sugar.  If you boil sugar and water together (simple syrup), you get that consistency.  If you boiled it without the sugar, you'd end up with an empty pot after the water had boiled off, but would never see a change in the consistency beyond the water evaporating into steam.

It's unclear what you mean when you say you're trying to use this "syrup" to absorb other flavors.  Certainly you can use a milder, "unflavored" syrup such as simple or agave in a savory preparation, as long as you tone down the inherent sweetness with fat, salt, or acid, but the use of a syrup is largely textural, and it doesn't seem to me that a "syrup" is really what you're looking for. A syrup is, in itself, a flavor component in addition to all its other qualities that I and others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> I need this syrup to absorb other flavors as I'm trying to make something savory

Rather than a syrup, you seem to be looking for an [extract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract#Extraction_techniques) or an [infusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infusion). Whether it's vanilla extract, chilli oil or lemon peel oil, they all absorb the flavour or aromas of the compounds without any sweetness.

The high temperatures used in baking can affect some of the flavour depending on what you use.

If the consistency of your final product needs approach a standard simple syrup as well you'd need to create a base liquid, flavour it with your extract and thicken it as [Jay](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/59620/25798) explains.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps chia seeds will work for you?

When you add water or other liquid, the seeds are transformed into a gelatinous mass. The gelatin will take on the taste of whatever you add to it.

A typical ratio is 9:1 (such as 3 cups of water to 1/3 cup chia seeds. To change the consistency, add more or less water (or whatever liquid you want to use).

Answer (score 0):

[Methyl cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_cellulose) (food grade wallpaper paste) is as flavourless and syrupy as you can get. It is used in many barcode products like salad dressing, and savoury sauces

$100 for a 5Kg bag, 20g makes a litre